# How to set a check if coupon code used one time then do not allow to use it second time in one transection

Tags: javascript, jquery

**This is my code**
**html input field**

```
<input type="text" size = "3" name="couponadd" id="couponadd" 
oninput="myFunction()" class="field" placeholder="Enter Coupon Code" />
```

**Script Code**

```
<script>
var lastval;
function myFunction() {
```

**getting  CouponDC,TicketypDC and CouponPrcDC from database**

```
 var CouponDC = $('#dbcoupan').val();
 var TicketypDC = $('#dbtckettype').val();
 var CouponPrcDC = $('#dbprice').val();
var total_price = $('#total_price').val();
```

**Get getcoupon from input**

```
var getcoupon = $("#couponadd").val(),
 txt='Invaild Coupon';
```

**check if user enter same coupon**

```
 if(getcoupon == lastval )
 {
 alert('You Cant Enter Same Code Again');
 }
```

**if coupon code match with database coupon**

```
  else if (getcoupon == CouponDC ) {
  $amount=CouponPrcDC;
  total_price = total_price * ((100-$amount) / 100);
```

**minus some ammout from total if match**

```
  total_price = Math.round(total_price);
  document.getElementById('Voucher_value').value = total_price;
  }
```

**if coupo don't match with database coupon**

```
  else if(getcoupon != CouponDC && getcoupon.length ==5 )
  {
  alert('WRONG COUPON CODE');
  }
 **store last value enter in input**

  lastval = getcoupon;
   $('#total_price').val(total_price);
}
</script>
```

Comment: share a fiddler or snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in an array and check if it exists before moving ahead.

Pseudo code below:

```
var couponArr = [];
var getcoupon = $("#couponadd").val();
if($.inArray(getcoupon, couponArr) !== -1) {
    alert('Coupon already used, can\'t use again.');
} else {
    couponArr.push(getcoupon);
    // your code here.. 
}
```

`inArray` returns the index of the element in the array, not a boolean indicating if the item exists in the array. If the element was not found, `-1` will be returned.

Comment: Not working sir..show alert message very first when enter whatever  something

Comment: @monuDevP - Got it. Just swap the code in conditions. Have updated the code.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with my code.i think there is a mistake

Comment: Iam using function here oninput ..with your code function not working

Comment: As I mentioned, its a pseudo code. As I understand from your code, just add `var couponArr = [];` at the beginning. Instead of your `if` condition, use this one `if($.inArray(getcoupon, couponArr) !== -1) {` and lastly, instead of `lastval = getcoupon;`, you should do `couponArr.push(getcoupon);`

Comment: and if someone use right code first time and second time wrong or something else in input..then after again user use the right code it definitely apply again

Answer (score 0):

Add a global tag variable and set default to false，use a if condition wrap the code need to run，then in the run code set it to true.

such as：

```
// in outer space
var hasCodeRun = false;


// in some function
if （!hasCodeRun） {
   // run code here
   hasCodeRun = true;
}
```

Comment: where i have to put this part :if （!hasCodeRun） { } ??

Comment: just wrap the coupon code that you don't allow to be used for  second time