# How to protect input to Re-enter the value again?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

**This is my code**

```
 <input type="text" size = "3" name="couponadd" id="couponadd" oninput="myFunction()" class="field" placeholder="Enter Coupon Code" />
```

**script code**

```
function myFunction() {
var getcoupon = $("#couponadd").val();
}
```

**DB values**

```
$Type =$_POST['type'];
  $Id=$_POST["id"];
$sqlData = array();
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where Id =? AND type= ?");
```

**bind the param**

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $Id,$Type);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

**bind the results**

```
$stmt-> bind_result($Id,$type,$Coupon_Code);
$numRows = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numRows > 0) {
while($stmt->fetch())
{
```

**array**

```
$data[] = array($Id,$type,$Coupon_Code);
$NEventid=$Id;
$NCoupon_Code=$Coupon_Code;
$NTickettype=$Tickettype;
$NCouponPrice=$CouponPrice;
```

**use values in hidden inputs**

```
echo "<input type='hidden' id='dbcoupan' value='".$NCoupon_Code."' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' id='dbtckettype' value='".$NTickettype."' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' id='dbprice' value='".$NCouponPrice."' />";
```

Comment: it is unclear what you're asking. all your code does is get the value of input and store it in a variable getcoupon which is local to the function

Comment: I am Using coupon code here but if someone use Coupon code again it should show alert message.Coupon code must be applied only one time only

Comment: edit your question

Comment: @monuDevP Sounds like you will need a database of already-used coupons on your server

Comment: @SagarV check the full code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440478/how-to-set-a-check-if-coupon-code-used-one-time-then-do-not-allow-to-use-it-seco

Comment: @Bergi sir i got the coupons from from DB .You can check my full code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440478/how-to-set-a-check-if-coupon-code-used-one-time-then-do-not-allow-to-use-it-seco

Comment: no. there is no db in that code

Comment: @monuDevP Please post the full code in your question.

Comment: @SagarV check updated code .and other code on same link

Comment: @Bergi i just post the short code here ..see my DB values in updated code.and other code is on the same link

Comment: @monuDevP And how did you try to get the DB values to the client? Or rather, the client code that needs to be checked to the server?

Comment: @Bergi First of all i get the coupon code from Db then store into hidden values then after  i  compare it with input which user enter

Comment: @monuDevP Where's the code for *that*? And what does not work about it?

Comment: @Bergi  sir.i am checking the coupon code in JS..See the code Link which i posted to you in previous comments....See again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440478/how-to-set-a-check-if-coupon-code-used-one-time-then-do-not-allow-to-use-it-seco

Comment: @monuDevP If that's the approach you want to go, the database code is not relevant to the question at all. Please post only what the markup of the input and the hidden values looks like that the browser receives.

Comment: @Bergi sir  Code is in running and working perfectly.I just need to check if user enter same coupon  again

Comment: Enter again, after what? Isn't the previously entered in the hidden values already?

Comment: @Bergi sir  if you check the full code you'll understand everything what is happing in the code..